# Why isn't my image updating on my JPanel?

Tags: java, google-maps, jpanel, jlabel

https://pastebin.com/Mfj4pX2c

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AWG_Widget extends JPanel {

    public static final int mapWidth = 300;
    public static final int mapHeight = 300;

    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    JPanel northPanel, centerPanel;
    JButton bt_GetMap;
    //Holds the map
    JLabel map;
    ImageIcon mapIcon;
    // Combo Box for the types of maps: roadmap, satellite, terrain
    String[] mapTypesStringArray = {"roadmap","satellite","terrain"};
    String selectedMapType = "satellite";
    JComboBox mapTypesComboBox = new JComboBox(mapTypesStringArray);


    public AWG_Widget(){
        // Set layout
        setLayout(layout);
        // Sets a border around the pane
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        // inits panels
        northPanel  = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        // Creates components
        try {
            createMap();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        bt_GetMap = new JButton("Get Map!");



        // Add components to panels
        try{
            createMap();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Bad output");
        }

        northPanel.add(mapTypesComboBox);
        northPanel.add(bt_GetMap);


        // Add panels to layout
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add Listeners
        mapTypesComboBox.addItemListener(new ComboBoxItemListener());
        bt_GetMap.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    public void createMap() throws IOException{
        String imageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=10,-11.998672&zoom=6&size=612x612&scale=5&maptype=" + selectedMapType + "";
        String destinationFile = "image.jpg";
        String str = destinationFile;
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        mapIcon = new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon("image.jpg")).getImage().getScaledInstance(mapWidth, mapHeight,
            java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        map = new JLabel(mapIcon);

        centerPanel.add(map);

    }

    // Item Listener Class
    class ComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener{
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){

                if(e.getItem().equals("roadmap")){
                    selectedMapType = "roadmap";

                }
                if(e.getItem().equals("satellite")){
                    selectedMapType = "satellite";

                }
                if(e.getItem().equals("terrain")){
                    selectedMapType = "terrain";


                }
            }
        }
    }
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{

                centerPanel.remove(map);
                remove(centerPanel);
                repaint();
                revalidate();

                createMap();


                add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("Bad map");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                System.out.println("Bad map");
            }


        }
    }

}
```

So I am removing the component from the panel, and the subpanel from the main panel. I can get the image to go away, but when I call the method that creates a new one, I can't get it to show back up.

I know its creating a new image file because I can manually check that in the folder.

Why isn't this working?

Expected behavior: program has a drop-down box with the three types of maps that Google offers. I want to choose a map and click the get map button.

The button calls the get map function which creates a jlabel that holds an image icon created from the Google maps url.

I just want the program to remove the old image and add the updated image.

Observed behavior: I can remove the old image and call the create map function. The program feels like it hangs up for a Split Second which I think is downloading the new image but it doesn't actually update the image.

I know it's downloading the image correctly because I can manually check it in the directory folder.

Comment: Please tell the details -- What is the expected behavior of this program? What is the observed behavior? What *specifically* is occurring that shouldn't be occurring? What *specifically* is not occurring that should be occurring? What is the most pertinent part of your code, and can you describe what it is supposed to be doing *in detail*?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks and sorry. I edited my post.

Comment: I wouldn't re-create your JLabel. Instead create a single JLabel field to hold the icon and simply swap Icons when needed by calling `.setIcon(...)` on that JLabel. Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Otherwise you would need to call `revaludate()` and `repaint()` with each new JLabel that you create. But again, don't bother with this. Simply swap icons.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on centerPanel with each new JLabel that you create and add to it. But again, don't bother with this. Simply swap icons.

Simply change this:

```
mapLabel = new JLabel(mapIcon);
centerPanel.add(mapLabel);
```

to this:

```
mapLabel.setIcon(mapIcon);
// mapLabel = new JLabel(mapIcon);
// centerPanel.add(mapLabel);
```

and remove all code that removes the prior centerPanel and JLabel.

e.g.,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AWG_Widget2 extends JPanel {
    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 300;
    private static final String DEFAULT_GOOGLE_MAP_TEXT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/"
            + "api/staticmap?center=10,-11.998672&zoom=6&size=612x612&scale=5&maptype=";
    private Icon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(
            new BufferedImage(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
    private BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    private JPanel northPanel, centerPanel;
    private JButton bt_GetMap;

    // Holds the map
    private JLabel mapLabel = new JLabel(defaultIcon);

    // Combo Box for the types of maps: roadmap, satellite, terrain
    private String[] mapTypesStringArray = { "roadmap", "satellite", "terrain" };
    private String selectedMapType = "satellite";
    private JComboBox<MapType> mapTypesComboBox = new JComboBox<>(MapType.values());
    private String googleMapText = DEFAULT_GOOGLE_MAP_TEXT;

    public AWG_Widget2() {
        // Set layout
        setLayout(layout);
        // Sets a border around the pane
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        // inits panels
        northPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        centerPanel.add(mapLabel);
        // Creates components
        try {
            createMap(MapType.ROADMAP);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        bt_GetMap = new JButton("Get Map!");

        northPanel.add(mapTypesComboBox);
        northPanel.add(bt_GetMap);
        // Add panels to layout
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Add Listeners
        mapTypesComboBox.addItemListener(new ComboBoxItemListener());
        bt_GetMap.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    private void createMyMap() {
        mapLabel.setIcon(defaultIcon);
        try {
            createMap((MapType) mapTypesComboBox.getSelectedItem());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createMap(MapType mapType) throws IOException {
        new SwingWorker<Icon, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Icon doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // this code is all done within a background thread
                String imageUrl = googleMapText + mapType.getText();
                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
                img = img.getScaledInstance(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                return new ImageIcon(img);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    // this code is called on the Swing event thread
                    // get returns the Icon created in the doInBackground method
                    mapLabel.setIcon(get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.execute(); // executes our worker
    }

    // Item Listener Class
    class ComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                createMyMap();
            }
        }
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            createMyMap();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        AWG_Widget2 mainPanel = new AWG_Widget2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AWG_Widget");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
public enum MapType {
    ROADMAP("roadmap"), SATELLITE("satellite"), TERRAIN("terrain");
    private String text;

    private MapType(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

---

Also as per Titus's comment note that any long running code should be run the process in a different thread. For Swing the canonical solution to this is to use a SwingWorker. For more on this, please see:

[Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Also note that in my code, the JButton and its ActionListener are redundant since the map is updated by the ItemListener added to the JComboBox.

Comment: You should probably also address the **I/O** on the **EDT** problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, this code runs very smooth. Would it be possible to add the enum to my AWG_Widget class, similar to an innerclass?

Comment: @MrJank: Why not see -- what happens when you try to do this? (minus the `public` keyword of course)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It seems to work. We have not yet covered enums in class so I'm pretty confused.

Comment: @MrJank: yes, it will work. [The standard Java enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). They're useful constants and mainly add compile-time type checking that you won't get if you use String constants as well as ability to encapsulate some type-specific behaviors (methods) with each enum.